# See which data would be deleted before updating database

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6 Code First and have just changed my data model.
Now that I run the update-database command from the nuget package management console I get the error:

> Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data
>   loss. Set AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed to 'true' on your
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration to allow application of automatic migrations
>   even if they might cause data loss. Alternately, use Update-Database
>   with the '-Force' option, or scaffold an explicit migration.

I understand this error perfectly, however is there any way in which I can see which data would be deleted (before I run -force to actually delete the data)?

Comment: you can use update-database -force -verbose to see the executed SQL

Comment: @FabioLuz
I'm aware of that but I'm looking for a way to preview the changes BEFORE actually executing the sql (and thus losing the data).

Comment: I believe it's not possible, because it depends on the data in database. You could make a copy of the database, force the migration, and then compare the values between the old database and the new database. You could do this using SQL SERVER TOOLS - Data Comparison of VS

Comment: If this is a minor incremental change you may be able to just manually inspect the Up() code for hints. You can also do update-database -script to see the script without applying it.